# C++ Passing lambda as function parameter with argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, lambda, parameter-passing

At the moment I'm trying to build something like a Java-like forEach in a class where I pass a lambda and it gets called for every item. At the moment I've implemented it like this:

### Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    void forEach(void(*lambda)(Bar*));
private:
    SpecialList mElements;
};
```

### Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

void Foo::forEach(void(*lambda)(Bar*))
{
    for (auto& v : mElements)
    {
        // Try/catch for stopping
        try {lambda(&v.second);}
        catch (int) {break;}
    }
}
```

### main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Foo foo();
    foo.forEach([](Bar* bar) {
        std::cout << bar->something() << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

It works just fine, but I want to be able to pass elements by reference into the lambda to be able to work with later like in this example:

### main.cpp

```
int main() {
    Foo foo();
    foo.forEach([&var1](Bar* bar) {
        std::cout << var1 << bar->something() << std::endl;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

How could we achieve something like this? I've been trying but it gives the error *no suitable conversion function from... to...* and tried searching for previous questions and taking a look at how functions like std::for_each work but cannot make heads or toes of that. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at std::function

Comment: You could use from std::function and pass reference to data as another argument.

Comment: C++11 offers such functionality. Look at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each

Comment: [OT]: Better to have `void(*func)(Bar&)` instead of `void(*func)(Bar*)` as `Bar` cannot be `nullptr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda is not a function pointer. If it has no captured objects, it can be implicitly converted to one, otherwise it cannot.

A lambda has a anonymous type, so if you want to use the type directly, you need to use templates:

```
template<typename Callable>
void Foo::forEach(Callable lambda)
{
    for (auto& v : mElements)
    {
        // Try/catch for stopping
        try {lambda(&v.second);}
        catch (int) {break;}
    }
}
```

Otherwise, a lambda is always convertable to a `std::function` (even when you capture objects), so you could write like this:

```
void Foo::forEach(std::function<void(Bar*)> lambda)
{
    for (auto& v : mElements)
    {
        // Try/catch for stopping
        try {lambda(&v.second);}
        catch (int) {break;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried both sugestions and the second one worked just fine.

Comment: @Onelio, first should also work. Note that you have to put the definition in the header file as well - otherwise you will get linker errors.